# Is there any way to create a "signature" of a string to make sure that a string is unique? Or should I use unique DB index?

Tags: mysql, hash, unique, digital-signature, unique-key

I'm building a website. Users can submit "Title" which is a string of unicode characters (not just English).

When a user submit a "Title", I want to see if it's already in the database (MySQL). If it is, I'd just update the existing record. If it's a new "Title", I'd create a new record for it.

I guess the standard way to test for uniqueness is to just create an INDEX on the column "Title". But I'm concerned about the size of such an index because "Title" could be quite long.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to create a "signature" of "Title" and use that to test for uniqueness? Is there some hash function that would hash from an unicode string to a unique value?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Best solution is make Unique Index on `title`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is to use one of the MySql hash functions (MD5 SHA1)  to create a hash of each title and store this alongside the title itself.

You can then index the hashed value which will produce a better faster index.

These are basically cryptographic functions and eat up a lot of cpu, but your language environment might provide a simpler faster hash such as crc32.

Its also worth putting your "Title" through a cleanup before  hashing ie. coerce multiple  spaces to a single space, fold all characters to lower case remove punctuation etc.etc.

So the "STACKOVERLOW IS GREAT  ...... " and "stackoverflow is great" result in the same hash.

Comment: @James -- Is it possible that 2 different strings will hash to the same value under these hash functions (MD5 SHA1, crc32)? I just want to make sure that can never happen. Thanks.

Comment: @Continuation: with a _secure_ hash function, it is theoretically possible, but overwhelmingly difficult (i.e. no actual pair of such strings has ever been found). However, MD5 is _not_ secure anymore: collisions can be created in a matter of a few seconds (weaknesses were found in its structure). SHA-1 is "somewhat insecure" (finding a collision is still difficult -- and has not been done yet -- but it looks much easier than previously thought). Use SHA-256 (for which no weakness is currently known).

Comment: @Thomas Pornin -- Thank you. How big (how many bytes) is the value produced by SHA-1 and SHA-256? I want to compare that to the original string and see what kind of savings in size does it give me. Thanks.

Comment: @Continuation: SHA-1 produces 160-bit results, i.e. 20 bytes. SHA-256 produces 256 bits (32 bytes). You can truncate the result, but this lowers the security margin: to get protection against an attacker able to perform _2<sup>n</sup>_ operations, you need at least _2n_ bits. Traditional wisdom is that you should use at least 160 bits, but it will look "more cautious" if you keep a bit more, e.g. the full 256 bits of the output of SHA-256. Also, note that hash function output is binary data, it may contain zeros and other "non-printable bytes".

Comment: The tradeoff here is MD5 reuires a lot of processing, and the resultant 256 bit results are not ideal for a fast index, but, the odds of a collision are billions to 1. crc32 is quick, produces a nice integer for use in an index, but, the odds of a collision are about a million to one, not a problem for a few thousand entries, but for a million entries you will almost certainly have two different strings hash to the same value.

Comment: @Thomas Pornin -- all valid points except the OP no security considerations he only wants a better DB index.